# Converting HTML to PDF using iText

Tags: java, html, pdf, itext, pdf-generation

I am posting this question because many developers ask more or less the same question in different forms. I will answer this question myself (I am the Founder/CTO of iText Group), so that it can be a "Wiki-answer." If the Stack Overflow "documentation" feature still existed, this would have been a good candidate for a documentation topic.

## The source file:

I am trying to convert the following HTML file to PDF:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Colossal (movie)</title>
        <style>
            .poster { width: 120px;float: right; }
            .director { font-style: italic; }
            .description { font-family: serif; }
            .imdb { font-size: 0.8em; }
            a { color: red; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="img/colossal.jpg" class="poster" />
        <h1>Colossal (2016)</h1>
        <div class="director">Directed by Nacho Vigalondo</div>
        <div class="description">Gloria is an out-of-work party girl
            forced to leave her life in New York City, and move back home.
            When reports surface that a giant creature is destroying Seoul,
            she gradually comes to the realization that she is somehow connected
            to this phenomenon.
        </div>
        <div class="imdb">Read more about this movie on
            <a href="www.imdb.com/title/tt4680182">IMDB</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

In a browser, this HTML looks like this:

[image]

## The problems I encountered:

**HTMLWorker doesn't take CSS into account at all**

When I used `HTMLWorker`, I need to create an `ImageProvider` to avoid an error that informs me that the image can't be found. I also need to create a `StyleSheet` instance to change some of the styles:

```
public static class MyImageFactory implements ImageProvider {
    public Image getImage(String src, Map<String, String> h,
            ChainedProperties cprops, DocListener doc) {
        try {
            return Image.getInstance(
                String.format("resources/html/img/%s",
                    src.substring(src.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)));
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }    
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("results/htmlworker.pdf"));
    document.open();
    StyleSheet styles = new StyleSheet();   
    styles.loadStyle("imdb", "size", "-3");
    HTMLWorker htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(document, null, styles);
    HashMap<String,Object> providers = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    providers.put(HTMLWorker.IMG_PROVIDER, new MyImageFactory());
    htmlWorker.setProviders(providers);
    htmlWorker.parse(new FileReader("resources/html/sample.html"));
    document.close();   
}
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

For some reason, `HTMLWorker` also shows the content of the `<title>` tag. I don't know how to avoid this. The CSS in the header isn't parsed at all, I have to define all the styles in my code, using the `StyleSheet` object.

When I look at my code, I see that plenty of objects and methods I'm using are deprecated:

[image]

So I decided to upgrade to using XML Worker.

---

**Images aren't found when using XML Worker**

I tried the following code:

```
public static final String DEST = "results/xmlworker1.pdf";
public static final String HTML = "resources/html/sample.html";
public void createPdf(String file) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(file));
    document.open();
    XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document,
            new FileInputStream(HTML));
    document.close();
}
```

This resulted in the following PDF:

[image]

Instead of Times-Roman, the default font Helvetica is used; this is typical for iText (I should have defined a font explicitly in my HTML). Otherwise, the CSS seems to be respected, but the image is missing, and I didn't get an error message.

With `HTMLWorker`, an exception was thrown, and I was able to fix the problem by introducing an `ImageProvider`. Let's see if this works for XML Worker.

**Not all CSS styles are supported in XML Worker**

I adapted my code like this:

```
public static final String DEST = "results/xmlworker2.pdf";
public static final String HTML = "resources/html/sample.html";
public static final String IMG_PATH = "resources/html/";
public void createPdf(String file) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(file));
    document.open();

    CSSResolver cssResolver =
            XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().getDefaultCssResolver(true);
    HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);
    htmlContext.setTagFactory(Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory());
    htmlContext.setImageProvider(new AbstractImageProvider() {
        public String getImageRootPath() {
            return IMG_PATH;
        }
    });

    PdfWriterPipeline pdf = new PdfWriterPipeline(document, writer);
    HtmlPipeline html = new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, pdf);
    CssResolverPipeline css = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, html);

    XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(css, true);
    XMLParser p = new XMLParser(worker);
    p.parse(new FileInputStream(HTML));

    document.close();
}
```

My code is much longer, but now the image is rendered:

[image]

The image is larger than when I rendered it using `HTMLWorker` which tells me that the CSS attribute `width` for the `poster` class is taken into account, but the `float` attribute is ignored. How do I fix this?

## The remaining question:

So the question boils down to this: I have a *specific* HTML file that I try to convert to PDF. I have gone through a lot of work, fixing one problem after the other, but there is one *specific* problem that I can't solve: how do I make iText respect CSS that defines the position of an element, such as `float: right`?

## Additional question:

When my HTML contains form elements (such as `<input>`), those form elements are ignored.

Comment: Why the close vote with reason "too broad"? This is a *very specific* question with *very specific* examples. I added source code that results in *very specific* problems that can't be solved with the old iText functionality. The answer shows that using the new version solves the problem adequately. You could argue that there are duplicate questions (I could easily find dozens of duplicates), but the duplicates aren't as specific, and we really need a reference answer. Now that documentation on SO went down the drain, this is the only way to put a good question and a good answer on SO.

Comment: Because there wasn't a _specific_ question.  The unasked "question" here is, how do I convert this HTML to PDF.  The whole thing _is_ too broad. And the overall style seems a bad fit for the SO format, this isn't documentation.

Comment: OK, I'll add that question. Although it says "How do I fix this?" at the end. The question shows a clear path towards a solution, with one thing (absolute positioning using CSS) that can't be solved.

Comment: There are already many references to this question in the comments of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47872246 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47852780 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47830668 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47787253 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47808275 How many questions should I add to convince you that this Q&A are useful? If I can't convince you, please reintroduce the SO documentation functionality so that I can add this content as a documentation topic (or provide an alternative solution).

Comment: I am no longer affiliated with any of the iText companies. See my LinkedIn profile for more info.

Comment: can you see this ref : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77355363/lambda-spring-boot-converting-html-to-pdf for me please

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## Why your code doesn't work

As explained in the introduction of the [HTML to PDF tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml), `HTMLWorker` has been deprecated many years ago. It wasn't intended to convert complete HTML pages. It doesn't know that an HTML page has a `<head>` and a `<body>` section; it just parses all the content. It was meant to parse small HTML snippets, and you could define styles using the `StyleSheet` class; real CSS wasn't supported.

Then came XML Worker. XML Worker was meant as a generic framework to parse XML. As a proof of concept, we decided to write some XHTML to PDF functionality, but we didn't support all of the HTML tags. For instance: forms weren't supported at all, and it was very hard to support CSS that is used to position content. Forms in HTML are very different from forms in PDF. There was also a mismatch between the iText architecture and the architecture of HTML + CSS. Gradually, we extended XML Worker, mostly based on requests from customers, but XML Worker became a monster with many tentacles.

Eventually, we decided to rewrite iText from scratch, with the requirements for HTML + CSS conversion in mind. This resulted in [iText 7](https://itextpdf.com/itext-7-core). On top of iText 7, we created several add-ons, the most important one in this context being [pdfHTML](https://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfHTML).

## How to solve the problem

Using the latest version of iText (iText 7.1.0 + pdfHTML 2.0.0) the code to convert the HTML from the question to PDF is reduced to this snippet:

```
public static final String SRC = "src/main/resources/html/sample.html";
public static final String DEST = "target/results/sample.pdf";
public void createPdf(String src, String dest) throws IOException {
    HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new File(src), new File(dest));
}
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, this is pretty much the result you'd expect. Since iText 7.1.0 / pdfHTML 2.0.0, the default font is Times-Roman. The CSS is being respected: the image is now floating on the right.

## Some additional thoughts.

Developers often feel opposed to upgrade to a newer iText version when I give the advice to upgrade to iText 7 / pdfHTML 2. Allow me to answer to the top 3 of arguments I hear:

*I need to use the free iText, and iText 7 isn't free / the pdfHTML add-on is closed source.*

iText 7 is released using the AGPL, just like iText 5 and XML Worker. The AGPL allows *free use* in the sense of *free of charge* in the context of open source projects. If you are distributing a closed source / proprietary product (e.g. you use iText in a SaaS context), you can't use iText for free; in that case, you have to purchase a commercial license. This was already true for iText 5; this is still true for iText 7. As for versions prior to iText 5: [you shouldn't use these at all](https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/versions-older-than-5). Regarding pdfHTML: the first versions were indeed only available as closed source software. We have had heavy discussion within iText Group: on the one hand, there were the people who wanted to avoid the massive abuse by companies who don't listen to their developers when those developers tell the powers that be that open source isn't the same as free. Developers were telling us that their boss forced them to do the wrong thing, and that they couldn't convince their boss to purchase a commercial license. On the other hand, there were the people who argued that we shouldn't punish developers for the wrong behavior of their bosses. Eventually, the people in favor of open sourcing pdfHTML, that is: the developers at iText, won the argument. Please prove that they weren't wrong, and use iText correctly: respect the AGPL if you're using iText *for free*; make sure that your boss purchases a commercial license if you're using iText in a closed source context.

*I need to maintain a legacy system, and I have to use an old iText version.*

Seriously? Maintenance also involves applying upgrades and migrating to new versions of the software you're using. As you can see, the code needed when using iText 7 and pdfHTML is very simple, and less error-prone than the code needed before. A migration project shouldn't take too long.

*I've only just started and I didn't know about iText 7; I only found out after I finished my project.*

That's why I'm posting this question and answer. Think of yourself as an eXtreme Programmer. Throw away all of your code, and start anew. You'll notice that it's not as much work as you imagined, and you'll sleep better knowing that you've made your project future-proof because iText 5 is being phased out. We still offer support to paying customers, but eventually, we'll stop supporting iText 5 altogether.

Comment: *"the developers at iText, won the argument. Please prove that they were wrong, and use iText correctly"* - don't you mean "prove that they were right"? As is I would think "they" refers to the developers...

Comment: Good catch, @mkl, the text said the opposite of what I meant.

Comment: Hi @Bruno, thank you for the answer, but i have another requirement of converting the same html page to excel does this happen using ItextSharp-7

Comment: No, it would surprise me if you could find a tool that can convert any web page to Excel. HTML and Excel have totally different purposes. Take for instance the page https://lowagie.com What would that page look like in Excel? Would it make sense to convert such a page to Excel? (No, it wouldn't.)

Comment: Hi @BrunoLowagie I am trying to convert HTML to PDF, but takes too much time to convert. records over 40000... html file size is nearly 1gb. How can i reduce convertion time. Any suggestions?

Comment: @DanielASathishKumar "html file size is nearly 1gb". Wow, I hope you refer to not only the html but also the size of the images and files linked in it and I wonder if you really need those huge fles embedded in the PDF. Perhaps a link to a corporate/public server instead?

Comment: @DanielASathishKumar If there are more than 40,000 records, then converting these records to HTML first, and then creating a PDF is a wrong design choice. Please ask your manager to replace the architect who came up with this design.

Comment: FYI peeps, this works well even with badly formed html - it wont break the conversion like itext5 used too.

Comment: Hi @BrunoLowagie, thank you for your response, Actually we have separate servers for our reporting systems. Our reporting application uses crystal reports. So now we are trying to convert the crystal reports into html reports. And there we gave an option to download a report as PDF that causes us problem. Any suggestions to get things done?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie, Already informed to my manager and hold that process. But still we look for better architect to accomplish. Is there any other way to accomplish?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie hi Bruno i'm using itext7.pdfhtml now but also  there are bunch of css properties not recognize by pdfhtml dll my source code is in this link https://gofile.io/d/vQqULH

Comment: I believe HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new File(src), new File(dest)); is depreciated now. Using HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(htmlString, new FileStream("mypdf.pdf", FileMode.Create)); should work instead!

Answer (score 8):

**Use iText 7 and this code:**

```
public void generatePDF(String htmlFile) {
    try {

        //HTML String
        String htmlString = htmlFile;
        //Setting destination 
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(dirPath + "/USER-16-PF-Report.pdf"));
        
        PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(fileOutputStream);
        ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties();
        PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);

        //For setting the PAGE SIZE
        pdfDocument.setDefaultPageSize(new PageSize(PageSize.A3));
        
        Document document = HtmlConverter.convertToDocument(htmlFile, pdfDocument, converterProperties);
        document.close();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: The classes com.itextpdf.html2pdf.ConverterProperties and com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter are coming from maven artifact com.itextpdf:html2pdf

Answer (score 0):

Convert a static HTML page take also any CSS Style:

```
 HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new File("./pdf-input.html"),new File("demo-html.pdf"));
```

For spring Boot user: Convert a dynamic HTML page using SpringBoot and Thymeleaf:

```
    @RequestMapping(path = "/pdf")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getPDF(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    /* Do Business Logic*/

    Order order = OrderHelper.getOrder();

    /* Create HTML using Thymeleaf template Engine */

    WebContext context = new WebContext(request, response, servletContext);
    context.setVariable("orderEntry", order);
    String orderHtml = templateEngine.process("order", context);

    /* Setup Source and target I/O streams */

    ByteArrayOutputStream target = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties();
    converterProperties.setBaseUri("http://localhost:8080");
    /* Call convert method */
    HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(orderHtml, target, converterProperties);

    /* extract output as bytes */
    byte[] bytes = target.toByteArray();


    /* Send the response as downloadable PDF */

    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=order.pdf")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF)
            .body(bytes);

}
```