# export to pdf with html decode

Tags: html, asp.net, pdf, gridview, itext

I want to display one column (from a data source, using GridView) with html tags into a PDF .
I want the HTML to be decoded so that in the PDF, it won't print the literal html tags . here's my code:

In GridView_RowDataBound event:

```
for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if (GridView1.Rows[i].RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {

            for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
            {
                decodeHTML = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text);
                GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text = decodeHTML;
            }
        }
    }
```

then added the HTML decoded gridview into PDF cell:

```
    Phrase cellText = new Phrase(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text, baseFontNormal);


    iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(cellText);
    if (j == 3) cell.HorizontalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER;
    table.AddCell(cell);
```

Instead of displaying the data in a PDF format, it displays them in an HTML page (in browser). However, it will be displayed as PDF file ONLY if I remove the **GridView_RowDataBound** event, but then the data will print literal html tags, and I don't want this.

Comment: *"Instead of displaying the data in a PDF format, it displays them in an HTML page (in browser)."* - if an html page is displayed instead of a pdf, you obviously return html and not pdf. So take a look at the code that writes to the response.

Comment: but when I remove (comment out) the code in the GridView_RowDataBound event, it exports as a PDF file as expected.

Comment: Hi @mkl, I think that the OP is making the wrong assumption about the `HtmlDecode` method.

Comment: @mkl nope, that's not the case, Bruno Lowagie is correct

Comment: Yes, because "it displays them in an HTML page" was not an exact description, the page was a pdf page which merely showed some html source...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making the wrong assumption about the `HtmlDecode` method. You assume that this method can decode HTML, e.g. `<p>This is <i>italic</i> and this is <b>bold</b>!</p>` into something like:

> This is *italic* and this is **bold**!

But that is not the case. Take a look at the [API documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN:

> Converts a string that has been HTML-encoded for HTTP transmission into a decoded string.

What does this mean?

It means that you can use `HtmlDecode` to convert a string like this:

```
&lt;p&gt;This is &lt;i&gt;italic&lt;/i&gt; and this is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;!&lt;/p&gt;
```

Into a string like this:

```
<p>This is <i>italic</i> and this is <b>bold</b>!</p>
```

The `HtmlDecode` method *does not* remove the tags. It makes sure that entities in the string (stuff like &) are converted to readable content. Hence it is normal that you see the tags in the PDF.

When you have HTML content, and you want to convert it to iText objects, you need an add-on to make that conversion. See [Converting HTML to PDF using iText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47895935/converting-html-to-pdf-using-itext/47896272#47896272)  to find out how to do this.

Comment: Thanks . That helps !