# iTextSharp Print To PDF Displays CSS and JS In The PDF

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I am using iTextSharp.dll to print my page to a pdf.  The only issue I am having is that the pdf displays the CSS and JavaScript that I have on the page.  Is there a way that I can set iTextSharp to **NOT** display the CSS/JS?

And yes, I have my CSS/JS typed directly into the .aspx page - as this is a small project.  Of course for a large project I would seperate it out.

**EDIT**
This is my current syntax that writes to the page

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=TestPage.pdf");
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
this.Page.RenderControl(hw);
StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
Document pdfDoc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4.Rotate(), 10, 10, 10, 10);
pdfDoc.SetPageSize(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4); 
HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
pdfDoc.Open();
htmlparser.Parse(sr);
pdfDoc.Close();
Response.Write(pdfDoc);
Response.End();
```

Comment: Although you didn't share any code, it is clear that you are using the obsolete `HTMLWorker` class. The problem you describe (the fact that the CSS syntax is visible in the PDF file) is an exact duplicate of one of the problems described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47895935/).

Comment: @BrunoLowagie - my mistake, I thought I had included my C# syntax.  I have updated my post to include such.  And impressive you can tell that I am using that class.

Comment: That's not so impressive as it was a known problem that was fixed by throwing away `HTMLWorker` and replacing it with something better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

had a similar issue for printing and solved by removing style using string.Replace method look at the code that might help you to solve the problem

```
  Regex regSimple = new Regex(@"(?i)<img\b[^>]*?style\s*=(['""]?)(?<style>[^'""]+)\1[^>]*?>");
        if (regSimple.IsMatch(html))
        {
            html = html.Replace(Convert.ToString(regSimple.Match(html)), Convert.ToString(regSimple.Match(html)).Replace("style=\"", "").Replace("height:", "height=\"").Replace("\"width:", "width=\""));

        }
```

Comment: how would I tie this into my current syntax?

Comment: html is a html text from url
WebClient client = new WebClient();
String html = client.DownloadString("url here");

Comment: according to your code change html with sw and put this line after 
StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());