# Error Generating PDF: ITextFontResolver: java.lang.RuntimeException: Font 'Courier-BoldOblique' with 'Cp1252' is not recognized

Tags: grails, flying-saucer, pdfrenderer

Recently needed to make some library changes so that could use `Apache POI` for `docx` suppot.  This included changing `Itext` versions from `2.1.0` to `4.2.1`.

Also using Grails Renderer Plugin with Flying Saucer.  From build.gradle:

```
compile 'org.xhtmlrenderer:flying-saucer-core:9.1.12'
compile 'org.xhtmlrenderer:flying-saucer-pdf:9.1.12'
compile 'org.xhtmlrenderer:flying-saucer-log4j:9.1.12'

compile ('org.grails.plugins:rendering:2.0.3') {
    exclude group: 'org.xhtmlrenderer', module: 'core-renderer'
}

compile("com.lowagie:itext:4.2.1")
```

When generating a PDF I get the following Exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Font 'Courier-BoldOblique' with 'Cp1252' is not recognized.
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextFontResolver.createInitialFontMap(ITextFontResolver.java:470) ~[flying-saucer-pdf-9.1.12.jar:na]
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextFontResolver.<init>(ITextFontResolver.java:40) ~[flying-saucer-pdf-9.1.12.jar:na]
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.<init>(ITextRenderer.java:124) ~[flying-saucer-pdf-9.1.12.jar:na]
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.<init>(ITextRenderer.java:110) ~[flying-saucer-pdf-9.1.12.jar:na]
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.<init>(ITextRenderer.java:106) ~[flying-saucer-pdf-9.1.12.jar:na]
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.<init>(ITextRenderer.java:102) ~[flying-saucer-pdf-9.1.12.jar:na]
Caused by: com.lowagie.text.DocumentException: Font 'Courier-BoldOblique' with 'Cp1252' is not recognized.
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.java:696) ~[itext-4.2.1.jar:na]
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.java:603) ~[itext-4.2.1.jar:na]
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.java:438) ~[itext-4.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextFontResolver.createFont(ITextFontResolver.java:483) ~[flying-saucer-pdf-9.1.12.jar:na]
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextFontResolver.createFont(ITextFontResolver.java:479) ~[flying-saucer-pdf-9.1.12.jar:na]
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextFontResolver.addCourier(ITextFontResolver.java:491) ~[flying-saucer-pdf-9.1.12.jar:na]
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextFontResolver.createInitialFontMap(ITextFontResolver.java:459) ~[flying-saucer-pdf-9.1.12.jar:na]
```

In looking at the code, the above exception happens from my code from

```
  ITextRenderer theRenderer = new ITextRenderer()
```

My code is running in a war deployed on Tomcat.  I can see the font files (like `Courier-BoldOblique.afm`, but they are in the jar `itext-4.2.1.jar` in `/com/lowagie/text/pdf/fonts`.

How do I get the code to find the fonts correctly, so that the creation of `ITextRenderer` succeeeds?

Comment: There has never been an *official* release of iText 4.2.1. Please don't tag your question as an iText question since you're not using an official version. If you *do* want to use the real iText, please read about [Converting HTML to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47895935/converting-html-to-pdf-using-itext). If you don't believe me, compare my name with the name you have in your source code. I am *that* Lowagie, yes. I know everything there is to know about the history of iText, what's official and what's not.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie: Removed itext Tag as requested.  I would appreciate any solutions you have about the problem.

Comment: I can't solve any Flying Saucer problems, nor any problems related to unofficial versions of iText. I did share a link to a solution to convert HTML to PDF using iText 7 and the pdfHTML add-on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the problem:

- The fonts are initialized in `com.lowagie.text.pdf.BaseFont` in a static initializer into local variable `BuiltinFonts14`
- However in `fr.opensagres.xdocreport.itext.extension.font.AbstractFontRegistry` in inner-class `ExtendedBaseFont` there is a method `clearBuiltinFonts` that is clearing the initialized `BuiltinFonts14`

Therefore the (ugly) solution is as follows:

Create a class:

```
public abstract class FixBaseFont extends BaseFont {

    public static void fixBuiltinFonts() {

        if (BuiltinFonts14.size() != 14) {
            BuiltinFonts14.clear();

            BuiltinFonts14.put(COURIER, PdfName.COURIER);
            BuiltinFonts14.put(COURIER_BOLD, PdfName.COURIER_BOLD);
            BuiltinFonts14.put(COURIER_BOLDOBLIQUE, PdfName.COURIER_BOLDOBLIQUE);
            BuiltinFonts14.put(COURIER_OBLIQUE, PdfName.COURIER_OBLIQUE);
            BuiltinFonts14.put(HELVETICA, PdfName.HELVETICA);
            BuiltinFonts14.put(HELVETICA_BOLD, PdfName.HELVETICA_BOLD);
            BuiltinFonts14.put(HELVETICA_BOLDOBLIQUE, PdfName.HELVETICA_BOLDOBLIQUE);
            BuiltinFonts14.put(HELVETICA_OBLIQUE, PdfName.HELVETICA_OBLIQUE);
            BuiltinFonts14.put(SYMBOL, PdfName.SYMBOL);
            BuiltinFonts14.put(TIMES_ROMAN, PdfName.TIMES_ROMAN);
            BuiltinFonts14.put(TIMES_BOLD, PdfName.TIMES_BOLD);
            BuiltinFonts14.put(TIMES_BOLDITALIC, PdfName.TIMES_BOLDITALIC);
            BuiltinFonts14.put(TIMES_ITALIC, PdfName.TIMES_ITALIC);
            BuiltinFonts14.put(ZAPFDINGBATS, PdfName.ZAPFDINGBATS);
        }
    }
}
```

And then every time add a call to this class before initializing `ITextRenderer`

```
FixBaseFont.fixBuiltinFonts()
ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer()
```

Answer (score 2):

This latest dependency (xhtmlrenderer 9.1.22) will resolve the issue.
Somehow fr.opensagres.xdocreport.itext.extension.font.AbstractFontRegistry  clear the BuiltinFonts14.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
    <artifactId>flying-saucer-pdf-itext5</artifactId>
    <version>9.1.22</version>
</dependency>
```