# java:convert HTML to PDF failed to process <strong> and <em> whth itext

Tags: java, html, itext

I want to convert html to pdf with itext  in my java code,but it seems that the **strong** tag and *em* tag don't work.I try to search solutions in the network and tracing my code to find out why,but failed.Here are my java code , my html file and generated pdf snapshot below.

```
   public static boolean html2pdf(String htmlContent, String path) {
        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path);
                ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(htmlContent.getBytes())) {
            Document document = new Document();
            PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, fos);
            document.open();
            XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(pdfWriter, document, byteArrayInputStream,
                    Charset.forName("UTF-8"), new MyFontProvider());
            document.close();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
static class MyFontProvider extends XMLWorkerFontProvider {
    @Override
    public Font getFont(String fontname, String encoding, float size, int style) {
        Font cnFont = null;
        try {
            BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.createFont("STSong-Light", "UniGB-UCS2-H", BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
            cnFont = new Font(baseFont);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (cnFont == null) {
            cnFont = super.getFont(fontname, encoding, size, style);
        }
        return cnFont;
    }
}
```

and my dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf.tool</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlworker</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itext-asian</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>title</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p >
   <strong>overstrike</strong>
  </p>
  <p>
   <em>incline</em>
  </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

[image]

---

## Solved

I solved this by using itext7.

Comment: Why are you using a *maintenance* release of an old iText version instead of the latest version? I'm inclined to close this question as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47895935/

Answer (score 0):

In `MyFontProvider`, you are ignoring the `style` parameter if the first attempt to load a font succeeds (which presumably it does).

Comment: Thank you, but I'd like to choose the style basing on the html file rather than set a default style for the pdf file.

Comment: Yes, if you use the style parameter, that's what you will do. I am sorry I am not an expert in iText, so I couldn't figure out how to do that.

Comment: Asian font families usually consist of a single *regular* font, no bold, italic or bold-italic font. If you needed a Western font family, you'd provide different fonts (e.g. Arial, Arial Bold, Arial Italic,...) to cater for different styles. With Asian fonts, iText needs to mimic bold and italic. I think you need iText 7 to do that.