# iTextSharp converting from HTML to PDF some CSS doesn't work

Tags: c#, css, itext, html-to-pdf

I'm converting from html to pdf using iTextSharp. the problem is some css style doesn't work when converted to pdf when I try something like  margin-right:500px; or float:left; it doesn't work. however when I try something like color:red; it works.
I'm using external css and this is how I'm converting

```
       MemoryStream cssStream = new MemoryStream(cssByteArray);
   MemoryStream htmlStream = new MemoryStream(htmlByteArray);
XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer,document,htmlStream,cssStream);
```

```css
/*css*/
/*this one doesn't work */
 .example{
float:right;
}

/*this one doesn't work */
 .secondexample{
margin-right:500px;
}

/*this one works*/
.thirdexample{
  color:red;
}
```

am I missing something? does iTextSharp has full CSS support ?

Thank You

Comment: iText 5 (formerly known as iTextSharp) does not have full CSS support. iText 7 (latest version 7.1.2), with the pdfHTML add-on, supports a lot more CSS.

Comment: Please read the question [Converting HTML to PDF using iText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47895935), and my answer to that question.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse is there any document on Internet saying what CSS syntax does it support and doesn't?

Comment: @sergiol neither myself nor Bruno Lowagie no longer work at that company and we are therefor unable to answer your question. Please contact Apryse (formerly iText) directly.