# iTextSharper with .Net core using iTextSharpLGPLv2.Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, itext

I am trying to convert an HTML document to PDF using iTextSharpLGPLv2.Core nuget library.

Problem i am facing is that HTMLWorker does not support in iTextSharper anymore.

Below is my code.

```
StringReader sr = new StringReader(sb.ToString());            
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);

        HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, memoryStream);
        pdfDoc.Open();

        htmlparser.Parse(sr);
        pdfDoc.Close();

        byte[] bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
        memoryStream.Close();



            FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"d:\REPORT.pdf", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
            fs.Write(pdfBytes, 0, pdfBytes.Length);
            fs.Close();
        }
```

Any alternatives to iTextSharper for .Net core?
or Any other way to fix this issue?

Comment: If you read the question [Converting HTML to PDF using iText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47895935), you'll get an overview of the flaws of `HTMLWorker`, which flaws were fixed in XML Worker, but also why XML Worker was abandoned in favor of iText 7 and the pdfHTML add-on. That question explains why your issue can't be fixed with the *unofficial iText fork* you're using, and that a recent version of the *real, official iText* is the best alternative for converting HTML to PDF.

Answer (score 3):

> Please note that it is not allowed to ask people to recommend a tool
>   or a library on Stack Overflow. Your question risks being closed as
>   off-topic for that reason.

There's also another problem with your question: there is no such thing as *iTextSharper*. I created the **iText** library (written in Java) and I released version 0.30 of that PDF library in the year 2000. A C# version was created a couple of years later. It was initially called **iTextSharp** (**NOT iTextSharper!**). However, when trying to trademark those names, we obtained the trademark for the name iTextⓇ, but a company named Sharp didn't want us to continue to use the name iTextSharp. Hence we changed the name iTextSharp to iText for .NET.

Today, we have *iText for Java*, and *iText for .NET*. We no longer talk about iTextSharp, and neither should you. I also don't understand why people talk about iTextSharper. iText is a Trademarked name; there should be no confusion.

Several people forked iText, and iTextSharpLGPLv2.Core is one of those forks. People using such a fork (such as you) are often victim of the fact that people creating forks often overestimate themselves and underestimate the effort maintaining a software library. My advice? Stay away from forks if the original project is still actively maintained. Forks are only useful when the original project owners abandoned their project.

> To make a long story short: you should use the real thing, not the copy or the fork.

If you want to convert HTML to PDF, you can use [iText 7](https://www.nuget.org/packages/itext7/) and the [pdfHTML add-on](https://www.nuget.org/packages/itext7.pdfhtml/). Please consult the official web site, and you'll find an [HTML to PDF tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml). All the examples in this tutorial are in Java, but it's very easy for a .NET developer to convert those examples to C#. It's mainly a matter of changing methods that start with a lower-case character to methods with the same name that start with an upper-case character.

**IMPORTANT:** I am the original developer of the iText PDF library and the founder of the iText companies.

Comment: Thank you very much @Bruno Lowagie, I will go through the web site iText.