# &nbsp; Not working while generating PDF from HTML Using itextSharp dll

Tags: html, asp.net, itext

I am trying to generate a PDF file from Html string. I have used `&nbsp;` for putting space between words, but it is not working in itextsharp. In pdf it is printed as word not putting space between words. As shown in below image.

[image]

Comment: Replace the `&nbsp;` with a space and the problem is solved.

Comment: no its not working.

Comment: can we see the code

Comment: Maybe you've spent a 2-year vacation offline and were unaware that iTextSharp was renamed to iText for .NET. Maybe you took an even longer vacation and maybe you're still using `HTMLWorker` (which was deprecated ages ago because it was broken beyond fixing). We can't tell because you don't show us any code. In any case, this post gives you an update on the evolution of HTML to PDF conversion with iText in the last decade: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47895935/converting-html-to-pdf-using-itext

Answer (score 4):

I dont know about iTextSharp specifically, but a next version of the library from creators of iTextSharp does HTML to PDF conversion correctly.
It is called **iText7** (Incompatible with previous iTextSharp); here is HTML to PDF package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/itext7.pdfhtml/

Usage:

```
HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(
    new FileInfo(@"Path\to\Html\File.html"),
    new FileInfo(@"Path\to\Pdf\File.pdf")
);
```

(method has many other overloads too).

Comment: as itextsharp was free to use in project. is itext7 is also free to generate pdf for various projects?

Comment: @PankajToshniwal it seems to have same dual licensing model as iTextSharp had. One is open source AGPL. You have to purchase commercial license if you are not willing to comply with AGPL. https://itextpdf.com/legal

Comment: @George Chakhidze can you provide me code sample for correcting malformed html using itext7 and itext.pdfhtml.

Comment: @PankajToshniwal "correcting malformed html"? That is NOT a responsibility of itext7 library, that's on you.