# How to convert html page to pdf with all stylings in asp.net

Tags: html, css, asp.net, pdf

I want to convert a html page to image format but it should include all its styling. I once successfully converted a html page into pdf but it neglected all its styling(External CSS). Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert HTML to PDF in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564650/convert-html-to-pdf-in-net)

Comment: You say you once converted an HTML page into PDF, and that it neglected all its styling. That's not the case if you use [iText for .NET](https://developers.itextpdf.com/itext7/download-and-install-information/NET). See [Converting HTML to PDF with iText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47895935/) for more info, or read the [HTML to PDF tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/chapter-2-defining-styles-css). Note: you will need the iText 7 add-on [pdfHTML](https://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfHTML) to do this.