# Error while writing storage open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) in android

Tags: android, itext7

I am Trying to write external storage on android version M it gives error but as same code i try run on the android version P it works Fine..

This error i am getting when i  run  on M.

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/PDF/Name.pdf: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
                  at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:87)
                  at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:127)
                  at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:116)
                  at com.itextpdf.io.util.FileUtil.getBufferedOutputStream(FileUtil.java:152)
                  at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter.<init>(PdfWriter.java:143)
                  at com.example.admin6.finaldemo.Fragment.Report.PdfCreation.SalesBillWiseReport.createPDF(SalesBillWiseReport.java:57)
                  at com.example.admin6.finaldemo.Fragment.Report.SalesReport$1.onClick(SalesReport.java:88)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5716)
                  at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10926)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22596)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
              Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                  at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
                  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
                  at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
                ... 17 more
```

My Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

My build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.admin6.finaldemo"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.13'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.itextpdf:itext7-core:7.1.5'
    implementation 'com.itextpdf:html2pdf:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

and My Code For Run Time permission

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        try {

                            boolean res=reportPdf.createPDF();
                            if (res){
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } else
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 101);
                else
                    try {

                        boolean res=reportPdf.createPDF();
                        if (res){
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

my createPdf Method

```
public boolean createPDF() throws IOException {

    File newFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + File.separator + "PDF ");
    newFile.mkdir();
    File file = new File(newFile,"Test.pdf");

    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("<table  border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=5 width=100%>");
    sb.append("<tr>");
    sb.append("<th>Month </th>");
    sb.append("<th>Savings</th>");
    sb.append(" </tr>");
    sb.append("<tr>");
    sb.append("<td align=center>January</td>");
    sb.append("<td align=center>$100</td>");
    sb.append("</tr>");
    sb.append("<tr>");
    sb.append("<td align=center>February</td>");
    sb.append("<td align=center>$80</td>");
    sb.append("</tr>");
    sb.append("</table>");
    sb.append("<br/>");
    sb.append("<table  border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=5 width=100%>");
    sb.append("<tr>");
    sb.append("<th>Month </th>");
    sb.append("<th>Savings</th>");
    sb.append(" </tr>");
    sb.append("<tr>");
    sb.append("<td align=center>January</td>");
    sb.append("<td align=center>$100</td>");
    sb.append("</tr>");
    sb.append("<tr>");
    sb.append("<td align=center>February</td>");
    sb.append("<td align=center>$80</td>");
    sb.append("</tr>");
    sb.append("</table>");

    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(file.toString(),new WriterProperties().setFullCompressionMode(true));
    HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(sb.toString(),writer);
    return true;
}
```

What would  be the solution for it and why this happens on below Android Version P and on Android  version it run Fine ?

Comment: On which device you are testing for Android M?

Comment: I am testing on Samsung J5 Version M. also i tested on Redmi Not 4 Android Version N.

Answer (score 0):

you can try it like this

```
File downloadFolder = context.getExternalFilesDir("Foldername");
File[] files = downloadFolder.listFiles();
```

get the storage here with folder name

Answer (score 0):

Try using **File.separator** in file path

```
String FILE = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + File.separator + "PDF " + File.separator +"Name.pdf";
```

Try to make a new directory if the path doesn't exist before passing it to the `reportPdf.createPDF` method

```
File newFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + File.separator + "PDF ");
newFile.mkdir();
```

Also, include the **Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** in the permission list where you're asking the runtime permissions.

**EDIT 2**

Also see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47896272/4079010

Comment: Not Working It gives Error  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/nio/file/Paths;

Comment: @ShubhamHingne try to print the file path in the logcat and let me know the result

Comment: I checked it not about the external storage when i try to store the .txt file it work perfectly but when i try to convert html2pdf using itext 7 it gives error on below P devices and on P it woks fine. if you know about itext7 then can you help me out please..

Comment: @ShubhamHingne I have updated my answer a bit. Please check now

Comment: @ShubhamHingne I have added a link in the answer. Please check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199818/discussion-between-shubham-hingne-and-rahul-khurana).